# Unknown pattern detection in a list of numbers

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have a sequence of numbers that follow some kind of arbitrary rule, let's imagine the following 5 examples:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
C = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
D = [15,18,21,24]
E = [2,8,18,32,50]
```

Sequence A follows a rule of ***x<sub>n</sub> = x<sub>n-1</sub>+1*** , where ***n<sub>0</sub>=1***, sequence B follows a rule of ***x<sub>n</sub> = x<sub>n-1</sub>-2*** where ***n<sub>0</sub>=8***, and so on. Example E follows the more complex formula ***n<sub>i</sub>=2(i+1)<sup>2</sup>***

How, using python, can I predict the next element of each sequence?

Comment: i mean i could also go 2, 4, 6 and it would go 8

Comment: like training an ai for identifing patterns in a string

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a curve using [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) if you have a specific function in mind, or you could do a [numpy.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) if you're confident that the "and so on" is always going to conform to some polynomial - your examples are all linear, so that's just a polynomial of degree 1.

Here's an example of using numpy.polyfit:

```
import numpy as np

model = np.polyfit([0,1], [1,2],deg=1)
```

This will take in your values [1,2] and map them to positional values [0,1] before calculating the 1-degree polynomial that best fits their sequence.

You then need a function to use the model to predict the n'th value in the sequence (Alternatively, use [poly1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html#numpy.poly1d)) but here's a simple polynomial calculator function that accepts coefficients as the first parameter, and a value of x for which you want to return the result of the polynomial:

```
def poly(coeffs, x):
    accumulator=0
    n = len(coeffs)-1
    for e,i in enumerate(coeffs):
        accumulator = accumulator + (i*(x ** (n-e)))
    return accumulator
```

So, we've trained it on a sequence with indices 0,1 - the answer for the 3rd point, with index 2 is found by:

```
poly(model,2)
```

Which returns the expected value of 3.

Here's an example using the sequence `[3,6,9,12]`:

```
model = np.polyfit([0,1,2,3], [3,6,9,12],deg=1)
poly(model,4)
```

Gives the answer 15. (OK, 15.000000000000002, but it's close enough - if you're confident that you're always going to arrive at integer answers then you could round to the closest integer - or choose some level of precision you're comfortable with)

This is all linear, for a quadratic model, you'd set the `deg=1` to `deg=2` and so on.

What this wont do for you is find more interesting patterns for which there isn't a polynomial to describe them. The [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) has a *huge* list of such sequences, but examples might include [The Fibonacci Sequence](https://oeis.org/A000045), [The Prime Number Sequence](http://oeis.org/A000040), or [Triangular Numbers](http://oeis.org/A000217) for these more interesting examples, you'll need to come up with a more nuanced approach.